# Parsing CDATA in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, cdata

I'm parsing XML which is on the server I read it and parse it There is no any error But I'm unable to see the data.

Here is my XML:

```
<BookData><book><Title><![CDATA[ABC]]></Title><AuthorFName1><![CDATA[A]]></AuthorFName1><AuthorLName1><![CDATA[B]]></AuthorLName1></book><book><Title><![CDATA[XYZ]]></Title><AuthorFName1><![CDATA[A]]></AuthorFName1><AuthorLName1><![CDATA[B]]></AuthorLName1></book>
```

I'm using `DocumentBuilderFactory` see the code even I set

```
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
```

But still not working please see the code for DocumentBuilderFactory

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setCoalescing(true);
try {
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    doc = db.parse(is);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    Log.d("XML parse Error:", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (SAXException e) {
    Log.d("Wrong XML File Structure", e.getMessage());
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There are lots of similar questions on StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+cdata+in+android

Comment: Please update your xml here, as this xml is not the correct one. So, that all future users can get benefit from this answer.

Comment: Hi Abhishek could you already find the way to solve this CDATA issue if yes please suggest me the way to solve this because i also having the same problem like you CADATA. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, you just have to pass InputSource instance to this method and it works.

```
private void DOMParser(InputSource inputSource) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = dBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);

            // get the root element.....
            Element docElement = dom.getDocumentElement();
            Log.i("Root Element", docElement.getTagName());

            // now get the NodeList of root elements
            NodeList nodeList = docElement.getElementsByTagName("book");
            Log.i("NodeList Length", nodeList.getLength()+"");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Element eleBook = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                Log.i("Book Node", eleBook.getTagName());

                NodeList titleNode = eleBook.getElementsByTagName("Title");
                Element TitleEle = (Element) titleNode.item(0);
                Log.i("Title", "Title - "+TitleEle.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                NodeList AuthorFName1Node = eleBook.getElementsByTagName("AuthorFName1");
                Element AuthorFName1Ele = (Element) AuthorFName1Node.item(0);
                Log.i("AuthorFName1","AuthorFName1 - "+AuthorFName1Ele.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

                NodeList AuthorFName11Node = eleBook.getElementsByTagName("AuthorLName1");
                Element AuthorFName11Ele = (Element) AuthorFName11Node.item(0);
                Log.i("AuthorLName1","AuthorLName1 - "+AuthorFName11Ele.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its typing mistake over the server there is no spell mistake. That's my typing mistake. Please suggest me how to parse CDATA

Comment: now you can try yourself also I guess there are lost of questions already there on StackOverflow buddy..

Comment: And also if you not able to parse the xml you should provide the problem that what is the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: There is no error but no data as well I want to display data in ListView Like Title will be the title and subtitle will be author 1st name and Last name Please All those question dint helped much..... Anyone know how to parse CDATA

Comment: Before showing the data in the ListView just try to parse the data of xml.

Comment: hi @AbhishekKarande i'm facing the same problem for my XML there are CDATA element in my XML to and after running not showing any error but only not displaying CDATA elements Data. i'm using this link for parsing :- http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/       i'm new to Android development can you please help me what are the changes required in this code for displaying the CDATA in my ListView thanks...

Comment: did u tried the Lalit's code?? It will surely solve your problem take NodeList and element for each tag thats the only solution I got till now..... Please try Lalit's code It will surely work...

Comment: can you plz give me some working code which works for CDATA file plz...thnaks...i'm unable to do this ...

Comment: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/ try this link for xml parsing keep everything same just make some changes in main class changes as given above from this link the source code is downloadeble try it take nodelist and Elements for each tags...........;)

Comment: @AbhishekKarande ,@Lalit Poptani i solve my CDATA issue simply by Using this SAX Parser Using SAX Parser i solve my problem http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser .  Thanks For your time and Support guys...

Answer (score 6):

This is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sample>
    <artists>
        <artist>
            <artistname><![CDATA[+&&&Plus]]></artistname>
        </artist>
        <artist>
            <artistname>015B</artistname>           
        </artist>
    </artists>
</sample>
```

Let's say you already have the xml file content as xmlString, the following methods will parse xml with or without cdata tag:

```
private static final String XML_TAG = "artist";
    private Object parseXML(String xmlString) throws Exception {
    try {
        Document doc = getDomElement(xmlString);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(XML_TAG);
        return retrieveData(doc,nodes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Logger.logError(e);
        throw e;
    }
}

static public Document getDomElement(String xmlString) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
    doc = db.parse(is);


    return doc; 
}


private Object retrieveData(Document doc, NodeList nodes) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodes.getLength() ; i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        String name = getValue(element, "artistname");
        list.add(name);
    }
    return list;
}

static public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
    return getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

static public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
    try {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE 
                            || child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE )
                    {
                        return child.getNodeValue().trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    } catch (DOMException e) {
        //Logger.logError(e);
        return "";
    }
}
```