# Android XML.parse() not finding content:encoded tag

Tags: android, xml, rss

I'm using Android's XML parsing helper (`android.util.Xml.parse(InputStream, Encoding, ContentHandler`) to parse this RSS feed: http://www.rssweather.com/wx/nz/christchurch/rss.php. It doesn't seem to recognise the `content:encoded` tag, which contains the data I am trying to retrieve. Here is the structure of the XML:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>...</title>
            <pubDate>...</pubDate>
            // Other tags
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[
                    (.... this is what I want to retrieve ...)
                ]]>
            </content:encoded>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rsss>
```

This is my code:

```java
void parse(){
    RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
    Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
    Element item = channel.getChild("item");
    Element contentEncoded = item.getChild("content", "encoded");
    // Have also tried these two:
    Element encoded = item.getChild("encoded");
    Element content = item.getChild("content");

    contentEncoded.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            Log.d("Test", "Content found: " + body);
        }
    });


    try {
        Xml.parse(feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream(),
                Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? :)  I can retrieve the other data from the `<item>` element such as the title or pubDate without trouble; it's only the content:encoded that eludes me.

Comment: Steve its Problem due to `<![CDATA[`...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193414/parsing-cdata-in-android

Comment: Aha, that looks interesting. I'll go read through and see if that sovles the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stick with your Android Sax Parser. I've faced the same problem and the solution to use content namespace and "encoded" as element.

You will find content namespace in the rss element:

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" ... >
```

So getting the Element looks like this:

```
item.getChild("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/", "encoded");
```

Comment: Sorry for not seeing your answer earlier; I finished that particular project months ago. I just came back to having a similar problem, and decided to have another attempt at making it work. This is the right solution. (I feel silly for not noticing the xmlns:content at the top of the page!)

Answer (score 0):

...i think that "content:encoded" is not a valid name for a element. It would be valid, if "content" were a namespace and "encoded" an element of this namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately that's what the RSS feed gives me, so I have to work with it regardless. However, as the code shows, I did try to retrieve it using namespace "content" and element "encoded" without success. I assume this is a specific problem with Android's SAX parsing helper class, as the DOM method linked in my answer works fine.