# How to add ampersand in the XML node

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have some streaming url in my xml, but I am getting this error.

Error : The reference to entity "s" must end with the ';' delimiter

```
rtsp://xxx.xx/username=user-a94b67f9bcb6b56173867177f28&s=5c57c5f5f4bd197a9214a13b6134d774
```

I can't change `&` to `&amp;` because the URL then can't be resolved, I also try URL shorten but that didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: `I can't change & to &amp; because the url then can't be resolved` Wrong.  Whatever is reading the XML will decode it.

Comment: I have try, it couldn't. When my app try to open the stream url which contain '&amp;' it force close app.

Comment: Then your app is wrong; you should fix it to properly read XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CDATA` tags in your XML to add the ampersands and any other special symbols like `>` and `<`.

CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.

```
<![CDATA[data]]>
```

Comment: I try CDATA, but app then can't get string value from xml

Comment: It might you parsed it wrong, anyway you should get

Comment: `<item><![CDATA[rtsp://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/b3.stream?username=user-a94b67f9bcb6b56173867177f28&s=5c57c5f5f4bd197a9214a13b6134d774]]></item> <!-- ch2-->`
This didn't working... App can't resolve url.

Comment: I guess that you are parsing wrong to get the CDATA value, so debug your application and check double your code which parse it

Comment: Yep, parsing the XML node and get the data from `CDATA` is bit different

Comment: @Emirnop You can see this to parse the CDATA in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193414/parsing-cdata-in-android